# Render static image in image tag in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I want to attach image to the image tag in angular 2.

I have following structure for my application,

[image: Structure]

In **choice.Component.html** view I want to show **UserDefaultImage.png** image in image tag.

I tried below things, but no luck.

```
<img src="../images/DefaultUserImage.png" />
<img src="./images/DefaultUserImage.png" />
<img src="/images/DefaultUserImage.png" />
<img src="app/images/DefaultUserImage.png" />
<img src="/app/images/DefaultUserImage.png" />
```

What path I need to add, to make it work?

Comment: Have you also tried for Tic_tac_toe.png?

Comment: That is also not working.

Comment: Are you using the angular cli, or have you setup a custom build configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move to the browser and inspect the element you will find the path of the image like this

> http://localhost:3000/images/DefaultUserImage.png

You should move your images folder to assets folder and use this

```
<img src="assets/images/DefaultUserImage.png" >
```

Answer (score 2):

From: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

> **assets/***
>   A folder where you can put images and anything else to be copied wholesale when you build your application.

It's work: `<img src="assets/images/test.png" />`

Comment: That only works for an angular cli project, or if the build is configured that way. It doesn't magically works out of the box for any project